# Image processing, replace picture background or cut out picture background

Tags: android, android-image, android-library

In an Android app, I would like that the user choose or take a picture of him from / with his device and then replace the background by another one (for example an awesome beach).

I'm looking for a library that can cut out the original picture background (the original background can be a color or maybe a landscape). Or maybe a library that can give me some tools to draw the part of the picture to keep / remove.

If a such library does not exist, I think that the "pixel replacement" method is the best way if the original picture has a color background (for example, I look for all the black pixel and change them with a transparent pixel).

I have found [this tutorial](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/image-processing-pixel-color-replacement/) but as you can see the result is not perfect. Is there a way to do not check only one color but a range of colors ? Is there a way to define programmatically the range of colors to check ?

Thank you in advance for your tips and links !